# specify build action of content - Nuget

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, embedded-resource, nuget

What is the simplest way to tell Nuget package to add all css files as an embedded resource (ie build action is embedded resource).

I am trying to do it through install.ps1 in the tools folder but still cant get anywhere

Note: I am creating the package from the directory structure(tools\content\lib)

This is my install.ps1 which does not work.

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)
$MsbNS = @{msb = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'}    
function EmbeddContent($ProjectLink, [string]$XPath)
{
    $nodes = @(Select-Xml $XPath $ProjectLink -Namespace $MsbNS | Foreach {$_.Node})

    foreach ($node in $nodes)
    {   
    if($node.Include.StartsWith("Content\css"))
    {           
        $cet = $node.ownerdocument.CreateElement("EmbeddedResource")
        $cet.setAttribute("Include", $node.Include)
        $parent = $node.ParentNode          
        [void]$parent.RemoveChild($node)
        [void]$parent.Appendchild($cet)        
    }
    }
}
$project.Save()
$fileLocation = $project.FileName
$dte.ExecuteCommand("Project.UnloadProject");

$proj = [xml](gc $fileLocation)
Embeddcontent $fileLocation '//msb:Project/msb:ItemGroup/msb:Content'
$proj.Save($fileLocation)
```

Help Please ..

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use DTE instead of messing with xml to change the BuildAction. From http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/227696:

```
$item = $project.ProjectItems | where-object {$_.Name -eq "ReleaseNotes.txt"} 
$item.Properties.Item("BuildAction").Value = [int]3
```

This link shows the enumeration values:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983962(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Mr Fowler, You Sir are Wonderful. :)

Comment: There are only a couple of BuildActions listed in that enum. Is there a way to specify "TypeScriptCompile" build action?

Comment: @BSick7, heh I'm looking for the same thing, find anything?

Comment: If you want to get to a file inside a folder, you have to get to it like so: $project.ProjectItems.Item("SomeFolder").ProjectItems.Item("ReleaseNotes.txt")

Comment: To set anything else do this:
$item.Properties.Item("ItemType").Value = "MyOwnBuildActionChoice"

Comment: These values match up with the list that's under Properties -> Advanced -> Build Action for a given file in Visual Studio. The documentation for VS2003 has been obsoleted, and it seems there's not another good reference. To get a value, just select the file using the DTE PowerShell code above, manually change the "Build Action" by selecting from the drop-down, then get the number by querying the value (e.g. `$item.Properties.Item("BuildAction").Value`)

Comment: Here is an updated link to the documentation for the available enumeration values: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/vslangproj.prjbuildaction?view=visualstudiosdk-2017