# How do you change the BuildAction of a C# project file using an enumeration in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2013, envdte, csproj, buildaction

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7423564/347172) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7427431/347172) on how to set the BuildAction (using Powershell) of a file in a C# Project.

Basically, get the specified item, then set the Value of the "BuildAction":

> $item = $project.ProjectItems | where-object {$_.Name -eq "ReleaseNotes.txt"} 
>   $item.Properties.Item("BuildAction").Value = [int]3

I'm just wondering if there is a way to utilize the [prjBuildAction Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983962(VS.71).aspx) values (it doesn't seem to work for me).

I've attempted to modify the second statement but it doesn't change the BuildAction:

```
$item.Properties.Item("BuildAction").Value = prjBuildActionContent
```

So, is there any way to use an enumeration value instead of `[int]3`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$item.Properties.Item("ItemType").Value = "Content"
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.